# Python: Is it possible to delay execution of default argument values until the class object has been instantiated?

Tags: python, class

In the example below, we see `C1.__init__()` has been executed before either of the class objects have been instantiated. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class C1:
...     def __init__(self):
...        print('C1.__init__ executed')
... 
>>> class C2:
...     def meth_C2(self, c1=C1()):
...         print('C2.__init__ executed')
... 
C1.__init__ executed
```

Comment: Yes, an object is instantiate here: `def meth_C2(self, c1=C1())`. And no, you can't avoid that. Generally, you set it to `None` and then use `if c1 is None: c1 = C1()`

Comment: `def meth_C2(self, c1=None):if c1 is None:c1=C1() ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @azro Thanks for your answers. That implies the caller of a class method must supply `None` for every default helper class (such as `C1()`) 'passed in'. That's a shame

Comment: @user2309803 no, you just make the default value `None` or any appropriate sentinel, so the caller doesn't need to worry about it.. See the linked duplicate

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are right, I forgot to instantiate `C2` before calling `meth_C2`, thanks again